# Checking if there is already another individual of parent class with the same object property value

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I am currently creating the "Prison" Ontology in Protege. The main problem is:
How can I (in a clean way) describe the recidivism (a verdict for the same kind of offense, commited by the same Prisoner)?

I want the Reasoner to search if there are any past verdicts of this type and state that this verdict is recidivism-type.

Here is a small screenshot (in my native language):

[image: Ontology part]

Comment: What is the role name between Prisoner and the Verdicts ? Object Property in protege

Comment: The role name is "received" in english:
[Received](https://sc-cdn.scaleengine.net/i/dcc31403ca05380d0b82108c25dddf0f.png)

Comment: Try to set equivalence relation in Protege.
In the WyrokZaRecydywe set field "Equivalent to" on the value:
received min 1 (received some Wyrok)

Comment: Ok but how the kind of offense is handled by this solution?

Comment: How are you representing *time*? You'll need something like that if you're trying to ask about **prior** offenses.

Comment: Yes, I had to rethink the ontology structure. In the state before it was a bit confusing. Thanks for the advice.